# How to copy string to system clipboard with php which runs as client side?

Tags: php, clipboard

I want to copy string to system clipboard with php(which is running as client script) on MAC OSX.

**Why I want this function?**

I'm writing a php script which runs as a client script on my MAC OSX. 
It's used to upload some text to a website , download some text to my local MAC OSX,  and I want to copy these text to MAC's system clipboard.

So, is there any way to copy string to system clipboard with php on MAC OSX?

Comment: add more details here please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP doesn't provide system clipboard api, but we can use php's **proc_fopen** to call shell command **pbcopy** on MAC OS X to retrieve this function:

```
echo copy2clipboard('string');
function copy2clipboard($string){
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
        2 => array("file", "a.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
    );
    $process = proc_open('pbcopy', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
    if (is_resource($process)) {
        fwrite($pipes[0], $string);
        fclose($pipes[0]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);

        $return_value = proc_close($process);
        return $return_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do this it will copy to the clipboard of your server, not the client.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed (running a local PHP script on my dev machine).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a **server** side scripting language, whereas "the clipboard" is **client** side. What you're asking is not possible using PHP.

Comment: PHP can also write client scripts. For example, a script used as upload text to web clipboard and download it as well. It helps me a lot in my work.

Comment: That's true, but not what you were asking. Using PHP alone this is not doable.